# How to get rid of line breaks and fill box with text/text wrap in python GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, text, line-breaks, fill

I need some help with this project. I cannot find the command to wrap text (fill box without line breaks) that I input into the widget. What I want to do get rid of line breaks when I push the 'wrap' button.  What I want to do is fill the box with text and get rid of the line breaks and wrap the text within the box.

```
from tkinter import *

from tkinter import scrolledtext
import textwrap

window = Tk()

window.title("Welcome to Text Wrap app")

window.geometry('500x500')

txt = scrolledtext.ScrolledText(window,width=50,height=20)

txt.grid(column=0,row=0)

btn1 = Button(window,text='Clear', command=lambda: txt.delete(1.0,END))
btn2 = Button(window,text='Wrap', command=lambda: textwrap)

btn1.grid(column=4, row=15)
btn2.grid(column=8, row=15)

window.mainloop()
```

I'm stuck on btn2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this:

```
def doit():
    data = txt.get('1.0', END).replace('\n', ' ')
    txt.delete('1.0', END)
    txt.insert(INSERT, data)

btn2 = Button(window,text='Wrap', command=lambda: doit())
```

Comment: `1.0` is not a proper index. Text widget indexes are strings, not floating point numbers. It works, but it reinforces a bad habit.

Comment: I changed it in the response, however seems they use floats in the examples in the doc here: http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/text.htm#patterns

Comment: Those examples on effbot are wrong. Indexes are documented to be a string of the form _line.character_. Consider the index `1.10`. As a string that represents the 10th character of the first line. As a floating point that is the first character since `str(1.10)` is `"1.1"`.

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using [textwrap](https://docs.python.org/3/library/textwrap.html#module-textwrap) you don't need to worry about the newline characters (\n), it will be handled for you.

Since you'll need multiple statements to be executed you won't need a `lambda` on btn2. Also, you need to exclude the function parenthesis on the button or it will be executed immediately without clicking the button.

Also, increased the geometry to `window.geometry('600x500')` since my window cut off the wrap button.

Try:

```py
# function - setting width to 50 since you set the textbox to 50
def wrap_text():
    orig_data = txt.get(1.0, END)
    txt.delete(1.0, END)
    txt.insert(INSERT, textwrap.fill(orig_data, width=50))

# Button - no function parenthesis
btn2 = Button(window, text='Wrap', command=wrap_text)
```

Results using test text.

Before hitting Wrap button:

[image]

After hitting Wrap button:

[image]